# Assume that $I/J$ is a prime ideal of $R/J$, is $I$ a prime ideal of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

$R$ is a commutative ring. $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R$ with $J\subseteq I$. Assume that in the quotient ring $R/J$, $I/J$ is a prime ideal. Is the ideal $I$ a prime ideal in $R$?

Comment: do you assume $J\subset I$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just compute the quotient, if $J\subseteq I$ then $I/J\subseteq R/J$ is prime means $(R/J)\bigg/ (I/J)$ is an integral domain, but the second isomorphism theorem says

> $$(R/J)\bigg/ (I/J)\cong R/I$$

so $I$ must be a prime ideal of $R$.